# Should I ask my question at Stack Overflow and get results faster instead?

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation, user-experience

As a well behaving user I placed [my question at dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81619/transaction-speed-benchmarks-for-mysql-v5-6-replication-seems-very-slow). But I see that the topics at Stack Overflow are usually mixed, and judging from the number of views/answers dba.stackexchange.com is not very active.

So, what comes to mind is that I could have placed my question at Stack Overflow and get faster/more replies... The worst thing that could happen would be a moderator moving the question to DBA.

Is that a way of abusing the system and being an evil user? ;)

May/should I delete it from DBA and reask at SO?

If people realise that using a more general place to post the question is better, how will the new branches mature?

Comment: Typically Stack Overflow users have some sort of obsession with code in questions.

Comment: And that question has nothing to do with programming. It was asked in the right place to begin with.

Comment: Posting this question on StackOverflow's Meta was a clever way to get SO members to go view your question on DBA.SE.  Well played :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart OP is a sneaky genius.  OP -- I think you posted in the right place.  I think you would have been downvoted or flagged if you posted this on SO since isn't not about programming.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.

As per the [asking guidelines on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), your question would be off-topic:

> Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

It would be summarily closed, most likely before users operating in good faith manage to write an answer.

> If people realise that using a more general place to post the question is better, how will the new branches mature?

By not allowing the precise behaviour that you propose. Branches should fail or succeed on their own merits. Just because a question isn't on-topic on any of our (active) sites that doesn't make it on-topic on others.

Comment: `...before users operating in good faith manage to write an answer` closing would be good faith here as well, given it's off topic.

Comment: It should indeed be closed, but I was referring to those users who'd want to answer the question without realising that it's off-topic. Given that SO is so active and the example question so obviously off-topic, close consensus would likely be reached before anyone manages to post an answer. So the OP wouldn't get any more answers even if he ignored topicality.

Answer (score 8):

No. dba.stackexchange.com is created, imo, because of SO getting too mixed with different topics. I think reasking your question on SO destroys the concept of the different StackExchange communities.

Comment: In theory I think everyone will agree with posting it in the right exchange but if the individual asking the question is searching for an answer and knows they're x% more likely to get an answer somewhere else for a consequence that equates to a tap on the wrist; its just a matter of how patient/well behaved they are before they post in a different exchange.  Not everyone will be like the OP who is trying to follow the spirit of SE (and I don't necessarily mean newer users)

Comment: It'd be quite nice if there were some sort of meta stack exchange, where I could look at question lists in my subject areas of interest across sites. I follow 'storage' stuff and 'perl' stuff (and a few other) on SuperUser, ServerFault, Unix/Linux, CS and StackOverflow. Would be nice to be able to look at one questions page.